# Как декодировать тело письма?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail

Python3 -
Мой код:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(MAIL, PASSWORD)
mail.list()

# Выводит список папок в почтовом ящике.
mail.select("inbox")  # Подключаемся к папке "входящие".

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0]  # Получаем сроку номеров писем
id_list = ids.split()  # Разделяем ID писем
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]  # Берем последний ID

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")  # Получаем тело письма (RFC822) для данного ID

raw_email = data[0][1]  # Тело письма в необработанном виде
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
# включает в себя заголовки и альтернативные полезные нагрузки
print(base64.b64decode(raw_email_string))
```

Получаю:

b'\r\xe9b\xbd\xea\xdeu:0\xa2w^\xad\xe6\xa5\x95\xba-\x82f\xa2\x95\xca&E\xe7\x1e\x8a\xf7\x9do-\xb4\xd3f\xb4\xe7\xad\xb5\xe3\xdd\x1b\xd3M4\xc2+aH\xc4\xcf\x89\xd7c\xd7W,\xa7}=\xdf_y\xaa\xf6\xd2j\xdd\xb71\xac\xb6\xd3m4\xdb\x8d\xb6\xdbN\xf4\xd0\xf0\xd3\j(\x82W\x92\x9a\xdaR\xa2\xea\xdcx\x00]\x84\xf2r\xc3\x97KO\xfa\xec\xab!J$\xb9\t\xad\x97N\xcf\xbd\xb3\xad\x93\xfa\x104Z\xc2\x01\xb0SX\xd6p\x9b\x10\xa2a$\x7fc$~+\x97\xec]\xde\x8c\x86>ml\xcb\x91t^q\xe8\xafy\xd6\xf2\xdbM6kg\xbc\xef\xce\xf0\x8a\xd8R13\xe2v~\xe6\xaf\xce5\xefN%\x8e-\xbd\xef^}\xd3m\xba\xf7\x8d\xba\xdb\xc4\x9a\xb7m\xcck-\xb4\xdbM6\xe3m\xb6\xd3\xbd4<4\xc0D$\x9ejX'

Нужно:

Request details:

Phone: +7 (912) 345-46-54

Time: 10:00

Как декодировать тело письма?

Comment: так вы вроде декодировали тело письма. или вы получили не то, что ожидали? тогда приведите реальный результат и желаемый.

Comment: @strawdog, отредактировала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам, помимо imaplib понадобится еще модуль email:

```
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(MAIL, PASSWORD)
mail.list()

# Выводит список папок в почтовом ящике.
mail.select("inbox")  # Подключаемся к папке "входящие".

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0]  # Получаем сроку номеров писем
id_list = ids.split()  # Разделяем ID писем
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]  # Берем последний ID

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")  # Получаем тело письма (RFC822) для данного ID

raw_email = data[0][1]  # Тело письма в необработанном виде
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
print(msg.get_payload())
```

Результат (на моем ящике):

```
<div>test проверка почты</div>
```